# Fetch image from S3 Bucket using React JS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, laravel-6

I have been trying to fetch an image from the s3 bucket to my react UI, my app is made of laravel and react, So I was able to activate the s3 for laravel, and it worked as I was able to render the images to admin end.

Now back to frontend which is made of react, I've been finding it difficult to do, I have installed

```
  "@aws-amplify/storage": "^1.1.2",
        "aws-amplify": "^1.1.40",
        "aws-amplify-react": "^2.4.4",
        "aws-config": "^1.3.2",
```

Please I really need help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm using using laravel to upload images to aws s3 bucket, so I want to use react to display the images from s3 bucket. Is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to work for me

```
<img src="https://AWS-OBJECT-URL.s3.amazonaws.com/IMAGE-NAME.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 2):

i faced the same problem  and solved the issue

```
<Image src={'http://innopizza.s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/abc.jpg'} />
```

Comment: mine is private image. so it does not work for me. Any idea? only logged in users should see this

Comment: This approach may throw CORS error depending on use case.

Answer (score 2):

<img src={`https://bucketname.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/foldername/filename.png`} alt="image"/>

**-the bucket and it's all object must be public**

**-exact access link of your object is "objecturl" on aws platform**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the problem has anything to do with your dependencies but more so with where your files are stored if youre not calling the bucket where they are stored you wont be able to fetch them

Comment: So how do I call it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding the s3 server URL before calling the image directory from the database.

Snippet;

```
<Image src={'http://innopizza.s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/'+this.props.pizza.image} />
```